# Junit GWT error - Cannot find function attachEvent in object [object Window]

Tags: javascript, gwt, junit, typeerror

I try to create junit test for my GWT application. The application uses [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org) javascript library. I encounter an error that seems to be connected with javascript code.

The listing of the [full error message is here](http://codepaste.net/hjo73x).

I think that the core (main cause) of the error could be the following:

> TypeError: Cannot find function
>   attachEvent in object [object Window].
>   (http://192.168.1.10:50987/com.qtitools.player.Player.JUnit/MathJax/MathJax.js#987)
>   (http://192.168.1.10:50987/com.qtitools.player.Player.JUnit/com.qtitools.player.Player.JUnit.nocache.js#530)

What could be the reason for not finding the attachEvent function? Thanks for any hints on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the HtmlUnit library does not support `attachEvent` function properly while running test in FF emulator. The solution is to run tests only in IE7 emulator.

To achieve that open in eclipse add `-Dgwt.args="-runStyle HtmlUnit:IE7"` to VM arguments.

Comment: I actually get this error when I include CHROME or CHROME_16. It runs perfectly fine with FIREFOX_10 and FIREFOX_17 whatsoever.